# If $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are continuous then $f|_{A\cup B}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $f:X\subset\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$ and $A,B\subset\Bbb R^m$ closed sets such that $X=A\cup B$ and $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are continuous. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

I've encountered this problem and thinking a little bit I got an idea which may not solve it, but I can't see flaws in it.

*Idea :* Take $x\in A\cap B$, then exists a sequence $(x_k)$ in $A\cap B$ such that $x_k\to x$. Suppose that exists other adherent point of $(f(x_k))$ which is different of $f(x)$, that is, we may write $f(x_k)\to y\neq f(x)$, in that way every subsequence of $(f(x_k))$ has to converge to $y$ too. Otherwise, we can look at the subsequence $(a_k)$ of $(x_k)$ that $a_k\in (F-G)$ for all $k\in\Bbb N'$. By continuity of $f|_F$ we have $$y=\lim_{k\in\Bbb N'}f(x_k)=\lim_{k\in\Bbb N'}f(a_k)=f(x).$$
Absurd ! So $f$ is continuous in $X$.

Is there some correction to make ? I would like to know if my the ideia of using Sequential Continuity can work.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x_k \in A \cup B$ and $x_k \to x$.
Let $I_A$ be the indices $k$ such that $x_k \in A$ and similarly for $I_B$.

If $I_A$ is finite, then continuity on $B$ shows $f(x_k) \to f(x)$ and similarly if $I_B$ is finite.

Otherwise $x \in A \cap B$ (since both are closed) and since $f(x_k) \underset{I_A}{\to} f(x)$ and $f(x_k) \underset{I_B}{\to} f(x)$ we have
$f(x_k) \to f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

One flaw I see is that you assumed that $(f(x_k))_k$ converges, which you don't know.

Rather, use the inverse-image characterisation of continuity. The result you are trying to prove is called "pasting lemma" and wikipedia has an easy proof.